# Find the centroid bounded by $x+y = 2, y=x^2, y=0$.

Tags: integration, centroid

I found the intersection point $(-2,4)$ and $(1,1)$

I decided to make everything in terms of $y$. Thus, $y=x^2$, $y = 2-x$.

So I will use the integral bound of -2 to 1.
$2-x$ is the higher curve, $x^2$ is the lower curve clearly from graphing

The formula for the $x$ coordinate is $\frac{\int_{-2}^1((2-x)-x^2)x \,dx}{\int_{-2}^1((2-x)-x^2)\,dx}$.

We can also then proceed to find the $y$ coordinate. However my calculations are not yielding the same $x$ value as the solutions which is$(\frac{52}{45},\frac{20}{63})$

Answer (score 0):

The region bounded by $y= x^2$, $x+ y= 2$, and $y= 0$ lies **outside** the parabola. From x= 0 to x= 1, y=0 is below the parabola and from x= 1 to x= 2, y= 0 lies below the line y= 2- x.  The x-coordinate of the centroid is given by $\frac{\int_0^1 x(x^2-2+x)dx+ \int_1^2 x(x^2)dx}{\int_0^1 (x^2-2+x)dx+ \int_1^2 (x^2)dx}$

Answer (score -1):

Let me redo this... the problem statement is a bit confusing, so I'll re-interpret it.  If you were given the problem from a book, please transcribe the problem *verbatim* so we can best determine what is sought.

Comment: Note the y = 0, I think you are finding the centroid of the part you didnt shade in. The small part on the positive x axis, from 0 to 2.

Comment: Are you sure? I think your diagram is wrong it should be shaded in the region of the x axis, y = x^2 and x+y=2, from x=0 to 2. How is that area you shaded bounded by y=0.

Comment: The equation $y=0$ is a horizontal line coincident at all points with the $x$ axis.  You seem to be confusing the $x$ and $y$ axes with regard to that constraint.